# Prove: Permutation of a root is another root of a polynomial

Tags: polynomials, field-theory, permutations, galois-theory, roots

I read that Galois group is a permutation of the zeros or roots, this is new to me, so, I have a question.

How can I prove, all roots of a polynomial are permutation of one another?

in other words, all roots has symmetric therefore, there is no asymmetric root (by asymmetric root, I mean a root which is not a permutation of another root) for a given polynomial.

I guess there is a relation between the proof and elementary symmetric polynomials but I can't go far.

Thanks.

Comment: not all permutations are members of the Galois group.

Comment: What do you mean by "a root is a permutation of another" ???

Comment: Technically speaking the Galois group acts on the roots, but not necessarily transitively.

Comment: If $f$ is a rational polynomial with roots $\alpha_1,\ldots,\alpha_n$, then elements of the Galois group are field automorphisms of $K=\mathbb Q(\alpha_1,\ldots,\alpha_n)$. Such an automorphism is determined by how it permutes the $\alpha_i$, so in that sense, an element of the Galois group is a permutation of the roots. But not all permutations are allowed, and you must, at some point, use the field arithmetic of $K$. Moreover, what you say about ‘asymmetric roots’ is only true if $f$ is irreducible.